# MySQL+VB.NET - Search in a column with a criteria, then select the highest value in the result

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET with the MySQLConnector, I have an ID column with differents values, i.e:

```
101
102
201
202
203
302
304
305
306
```

I want to select all the values that start with "3" and then, select the MAX of them, in this case, "306"

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select max(id) from Data
where left(cast(`id` as char(10)), 1) = '3';
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/w2tJP1T7ur

Comment: Got DBNull, here is my code. I'm doing something wrong?

        <pre><code>
myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(IDEmpleado) FROM empleados WHERE left(cast('IDEmpleado' as char(10)), 1) = '3'"
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Clase", Clase)

        conn.Open()
        Me.lblStatus.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar
        conn.Close()
</pre></code>

Comment: Are those real id values from your table that you showed in your question?  If no id values start with 3 in your table, then you will get a NULL value returned.

Comment: Yes, i had the values. I just changed the query to:

SELECT MAX(IDEmpleado) FROM empleados WHERE left(1, 1) = '3'

Worked like a charm, Thank you! :)

Comment: Notice that those are tick marks around the field name, which are different than single quotes.  I think in the example you posted you were using single quotes around the field name, instead of tick marks.